# Writing NSFilePromiseProviders to pasteboard blocks app on quit

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nspasteboard

In my Mac app, I'm writing [`NSFilePromiseProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfilepromiseprovider/) objects (initialized with fileType `kUTTypeFileURL`) to the general pasteboard on *Edit → Copy*. This way, the files can be copied to other apps, e.g., Finder. However, when the app is quit there is a huge delay (including beachballing) before actually closing the app and the Console log shows that pasteboard activity occurs. It looks like the system is in a way ensuring that the promises can still be provided.

All of the examples I found are using `NSFilePromiseProvider`s in the context of drag and drop from table views and I found nothing that writes the objects directly to the pasteboard (although it implements `NSPasteboardWriting`).

Through lots of experimentation, I've now discovered that if my own version of `NSFilePromiseProvider` returns `[]` at [`writingOptions(forType:pasteboard:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting/1525372-writingoptions) for all types, closing the app does not show the unwanted delay.

However, as I don't understand 1.) why the issue occurs in the first place, and 2. why the workaround circumvents this problem, I wanted to ask here to potentially gain some insights.

Here is the implementation of the `NSFilePromiseProvider` in question:

```swift
class FilePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider {

    struct UserInfoKeys {
        static let fileURL = "fileURLKey"
        static let row = "rowKey"
    }

    override func writableTypes(for pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] {
        var types = super.writableTypes(for: pasteboard)
        if let userInfoDict = userInfo as? [String: Any] {
            if userInfoDict[UserInfoKeys.row] != nil {
                types.append(.fileListTableRow)
            }
            if userInfoDict[UserInfoKeys.fileURL] != nil {
                types.append(.fileURL)
                types.append(.string)
            }
        }
        return types
    }

    override func writingOptions(forType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType, pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> NSPasteboard.WritingOptions {
        // If we return [] here, the app closes without delay and extra work by the system.
        // It seems that returning `.promise` for some of the types (which is done by the 
        // default implementation) flags some of the files to be made available to a
        // system-internal location, causing the app to block for a while when closing.
        super.writingOptions(forType: type, pasteboard: pasteboard)
    }

    override func pasteboardPropertyList(forType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) -> Any? {
        guard let userInfoDict = userInfo as? [String: Any] else { return nil }

        switch type {
        case .fileListTableRow:
            if let row = userInfoDict[UserInfoKeys.row] as? Int {
                return row
            }

        case .fileURL:
            if let url = userInfoDict[UserInfoKeys.fileURL] as? NSURL {
                return url.pasteboardPropertyList(forType: type)
            }

        case .string:
            if let url = userInfoDict[UserInfoKeys.fileURL] as? NSURL {
                return url.lastPathComponent
            }

        default: break
        }

        return super.pasteboardPropertyList(forType: type)
    }
}
```

The `copy` action writes the promises to the pasteboard:

```swift
@IBAction func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
    guard let urls = representedObject as? [URL] else { return }

    let itemIndexes = tableView.selectedRowIndexes
    if itemIndexes.isEmpty {
        return
    }

    var filePromises = [FilePromiseProvider]()
    for idx in itemIndexes {
        var userInfo = [String: Any]()
        userInfo[FilePromiseProvider.UserInfoKeys.fileURL] = urls[idx]

        let filePromise = FilePromiseProvider(fileType: UTType.fileURL.identifier, delegate: self)
        filePromise.userInfo = userInfo
        filePromises.append(filePromise)
    }

    NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
    NSPasteboard.general.writeObjects(filePromises)
}
```

and the respective implementation of `NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate` provides the files and file URLs.

```swift
extension ViewController: NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate {

    func filePromiseProvider(_ filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider, fileNameForType fileType: String) -> String {
        let fileURL = queryFileURL(from: filePromiseProvider)
        return fileURL?.lastPathComponent ?? ""
    }

    func filePromiseProvider(_ filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider, writePromiseTo url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        do {
            if let atURL = queryFileURL(from: filePromiseProvider) {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: atURL, to: url)
            }
            completionHandler(nil)
        } catch let error {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.presentError(error, modalFor: self.view.window!, delegate: nil, didPresent: nil, contextInfo: nil)
            }
            completionHandler(error)
        }
    }

    func operationQueue(for filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider) -> OperationQueue {
        return filePromiseQueue
    }

    private func queryFileURL(from filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider) -> URL? {
        if let userInfo = filePromiseProvider.userInfo as? [String: Any] {
           return userInfo[FilePromiseProvider.UserInfoKeys.fileURL] as? URL
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I've added a complete project for easy testing on my Github:

https://github.com/fheidenreich/file-promise-copy

Comment: You answered 1: "the system is ensuring that the promises can still be provided". Is the file content providing method called when the app quits? Does paste still work with your workaround? Do you write any other types to the pasteboard? Do you want Paste to work after quitting the app?

Comment: It's not the file content providing method that's being called when the app quits, but `filePromiseProvider(_:fileNameForType:)` twice for each of the copied files — my app doesn't seem to participate in the content provisioning. Paste still works also with the workaround and I can paste the files to a different folder in, e.g., Finder. And yes, the custom `NSFilePromiseProvider` also writes other types to the pasteboard, i.e., `fileURL`, `string`, and a custom type I use for table view drag and drop.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: OK, done (with link to project on Github).

Comment: The documentation says "File promises support UTI-based drag and drop functions", I wonder if copy/paste is supported. Apparently it doesn't work (without the `fileURL` type).

Comment: Yes, it's most likely really limited to drag and drop functionality (which uses the drag pasteboard then). Initially, I wanted to have only one part of the code that deals with copy/paste and the NSFilePromiseProvider looked prom... like the correct API. Thank you for looking into this, and also for all your other contributions.